# Smooth figure (.STL) in blender

Tags: smooth

The first picture is my project in Blender, the second is the same object exported as STL, and reopened in Blender. Do you know why the smoothing is so different? How can I solve the problem?

The file is too heavy for Subdivision Surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This site is for problems in Blender, not Chitubox so your question will most likely be closed. But the simple answer is: You have set the object to be "shaded" smooth in Blender. It's not the geometry that is absolutely smooth. Different softwares have different ways of handling this. The shading in Blender doesn't matter at all for Chitubox. So it shows the model shaded flat instead of smooth and probably this software does not even have an own option for shading the object smooth - but if so, you have to activate it there.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Chitubox doesn't have this option, so I would like to know if it is possible to improve smooth in blender

Comment: Use a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier and apply it. But this changes the look of the mesh and though the faces will then be smaller in Chitubox, they will still be shaded flat.